# Bug w IE8 Using Javascript to Insert Text at Caret

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Focusing on IE**, I have a textbox (single line `<input/>`) for which I need to insert text where the caret/cursor is.  The text within a div is inserted at the caret position when the div is double clicked.

**Bug: Text is inserted into the textbox, but at the beginning of the string in the textbox and not where the caret position is.**

The following code works fine using the multiline input (no bug), the bug only occurs with the single line input.

Here is the simple Javascript for IE *(other browser support has been removed for simplicity)*:

```
$.fn.insertAtCaret = function (tagName) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
            //MOZILLA support
        } else if (document.selection) {
            //IE support
            this.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = tagName;
        } else {
            //ELSE
        }
    });
};
```

Just so you have everything in front of you, **here is the JQuery that calls `$.fn.insertAtCaret`**:

```
$("#Subject").mousedown(function () { $("#InsertAtCaretFor").val("Subject"); });
$("#Subject").bind('click, focus, keyup', function () { $("#InsertAtCaretFor").val("Subject"); });

$("#Comment").mousedown(function () { $("#InsertAtCaretFor").val("Comment"); });
$("#Comment").bind('click, focus, keyup', function () { $("#InsertAtCaretFor").val("Comment"); });

$(".tag").dblclick(function () {
    if ($("#InsertAtCaretFor").val() == "Comment") $("#Comment").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
    if ($("#InsertAtCaretFor").val() == "Subject") $("#Subject").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
});
```

As you can see, when one of the two `<input/>`s are clicked, focused, etc., a hidden field (`ID="InsertAtCaretFor"`) value is set to either `"Subject"` or `"Comment"`.  When the **tag** is double-clicked, its `.text()` is inserted at the caret position within the `<input/>` specified by the hidden field's value.

Here are the fields:

```
<%=Html.Hidden("InsertAtCaretFor") %>
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="Subject" class="forField">
        Subject:</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Subject", "", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "required no-auto-validation" }, { "style", "width:170px;" }, { "maxlength", "200" } })%>
</div>
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="Comment" class="forField">
        Comment:</label>
    <%= Html.TextArea("Comment", new Dictionary<string,object> { {"rows","10"}, {"cols","50"}, { "class", "required"} })%>
</div>
```

Finally, here is an image so you can visually understand what I'm doing:

http://www.danielmckenzie.net/ie8bug.png

[image: bug behavior]

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a different insertAtCaret code I found from googling around.  Works on single inputs and textareas just fine.

```
 $.fn.extend({
 insertAtCaret: function (myValue) {
    var $input;
    if (typeof this[0].name != 'undefined')
        $input = this[0];
    else
        $input = this;

    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $input.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;
        $input.focus();
    }
    else if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.webkit) {
        var startPos = $input.selectionStart;
        var endPos = $input.selectionEnd;
        var scrollTop = $input.scrollTop;
        $input.value = $input.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + $input.value.substring(endPos, $input.value.length);
        $input.focus();
        $input.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
        $input.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        $input.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    } else {
        $input.value += myValue;
        $input.focus();
    }
}
});
```

After looking at your js code I'd change:

```
$(".tag").dblclick(function () {
 if ($("#InsertAtCaretFor").val() == "Comment")     $("#Comment").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
if ($("#InsertAtCaretFor").val() == "Subject")     $("#Subject").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
});
```

To the following:

```
$(".tag").dblclick(function () {
     if ($("#InsertAtCaretFor").val() == "Comment") {    
           $("#Comment").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
     }
     if ($("#InsertAtCaretFor").val() == "Subject") {                  
           $("#Subject").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
     }
});
```

Those two inline if statements with no ending curly brace look dangerous!

Comment: Thanks jfar, but the issue is still occurring in IE8 when the browser's settings are reset to default.  I changed my code to what you use as it is more readable.

Comment: @BueKoW - That stinks, I use almost the exact same code as you to do achieve the exact same functionality except I use single click inputs instead of divs.  I don't know what could be wrong besides a selector mistake or something.

Comment: It has to be something specific to IE8 and I can't figure it out. If I install Google Chrome Frame for IE, everything works fine. The problem is non-existent in IE9. I haven't tested this in IE7... I may change the divs to inputs for kicks.

Answer (score 0):

I've come the same problem myself in IE8. It seems that for **INPUT** `type="text"`, it does not fill in `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`. **IE9** does, however.